# color list in a general way

Tags: linux, parsing, colors, xterm

I thought this might be easy but not so much

I want to color the output of a command based on delimeters, in my case

`apt-show-versions -u`

and want to color the packages' names based on the colon seperator, or on the word 'to'. It seems to run into wanting a parser not a filter.

using color xterm on Linux and PuTTY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Others](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363143/output-in-color-bash) [have](https://superuser.com/questions/602294/is-there-colorizer-utility-that-can-take-command-output-and-colorize-it-accordin) been interested in similar functionality, I suggest you check  the tools (grc/grcat) mentioned there.

You might be able to get away with sed-magic, though. I'm not sure what you want to colour exactly, and neither do I know what the output of apt-show-versions looks like, but this colours everything preceding a colon and the word "to":

```
cat << EOF | sed -e "s/^[^:]*/\x1b[31m&\x1b[0m/g" | sed -e "s/to/\x1b[31m&\x1b[0m/g"
foo: 1 to 2
bar: 3 to 4
quux: 5 to 6
EOF
```

You can paste that into a terminal and see if it's what you're looking for. Essentially, it searches for occurences of regular expressions and surrounds it with ANSI colour codes:

- `s/X/Y&Y/g` : replace X by surrounding with Y, in the entire input (`g` flag), or, quoting `man sed`:

  ```
  s/regexp/replacement/
         Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If  success‐
         ful,   replace  that  portion  matched  with  replacement.   The
         replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that
         portion  of  the  pattern  space  which matched, and the special
         escapes \1 through \9 to refer  to  the  corresponding  matching
         sub-expressions in the regexp.
  ```
- `^[^:]*` : from beginning of line, match everything until you encounter a `:`
- `\x1b` : Hex 27, an escape sequence ([see here for more!](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php))
- `[31m` : ANSI colour code for red
- `[0m` : ANSI colour code for "reset to normal output"

If anything, this post taught me that `sed` captures matches in `&` ;-) Hope you gained some insight, too!

Comment: Thank you tremendously Oliver, regexps are always a bit of a problem for me, this works great. I modified things a bit, here's the command and some output

Comment: # apt-show-versions -u | sed -e "s/^[^:]*/\x1b[33m&\x1b[0m/g" | sed -e "s/to.*/\x1b[32m&\x1b[0m/g"

Comment: The output looks like bsdutils:amd64/bionic-updates 1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1 upgradeable to 1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2